# Mobile back end push and pub/sub (GCM or not)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

We already have a quite complex mobile backend written in Java which is deployed and works fine, so we do not have any need to use the Google mobile backend. Now we have requirements for pushing some data from the back end to the phone. Earlier I used GCM regularly. Our first requirement is only simple messaging, but it may evolve to something like a pub sub (phones subscribing to topics).

The issue I am not understanding is should I now use GCM like before, and later develop my own pub/sub overlay, or can I use the products Google has developed for that? Is this even possible, since everything I am finding on Google pages is just related to communication between Android phones via their cloud storage, so no library for communication between a custom back end and a phone?

In short, what should I use, regular GCM or is there something Google is providing which I am not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular GCM. A custom back-end can send messages to an Android app via GCM. The library for sending messages from a 3rd party server to GCM still exists (`com.google.android.gcm.server` package in the `Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library`), but you don't have to use it - you can implement the HTTP POST requests yourself.

Comment: But using regular HTTP POST means that I need polling, and that is not quite efficient, right?

Comment: @Alexander.S Where would you need polling?

Comment: Looks like we are not understanding each other. I would like to use GCM (or something similar) to push data from the service to the phone. That includes sending data to the google cloud, and than it will push the data to the phone. If I use HTTP post for that, than the phone has to contact the service first.

My concern is whether GCM is the right tool for this, given in mind that this may evolve to a pub/sub system.